# Exceljs How to addRow and merge cells

Tags: exceljs

So I need to generate an excel spreadsheet based on data from DB. Once I add in all the data from the DB I need to add in a new row at the bottom that says when the spreadsheet was generated like so:

[image]

I don't know how to get the cells to merge here, I can't use `worksheet.mergeCells()` since I don't know how many rows of data there will be in the DB. How would I merge the cells when using `worksheet.addRow()`?

Answer (score 5):

I have come across a similar problem and have used something close to this:

```js
const newRow = worksheet.addRow(["This report is..."]);
const currentRowIdx = worksheet.rowCount; // Find out how many rows are there currently
const endColumnIdx = worksheet.columnCount; // Find out how many columns are in the worksheet
    
// merge by start row, start column, end row, end column
worksheet.mergeCells(currentRowIdx, 1, currentRowIdx, endColumnIdx );
```